# is it possible to print time stamp on pdf document vertically and horizontally with python?

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to know if is there any library or utility/script available for python which can read pdf file and print custom text with time stamp at vertically and horizontally?

Comment: Could you please [describe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) the problem and hand out what you have tried so far?

Comment: it's a fresh start and looking for some kind of link or utility in python which can read pdf files from folder and print time stamp with some custom text on it

Answer (score 0):

indeed there are some libraries available in Python that support PDF reading and also writing. For your particular question I would recommend four libraries:

1. PyPDF2 (can read and write PDF files)
2. reportlab (which can be used for manipulating PDFs with pictures and text)
3. datetime (which can be used to configure timestamps)
4. os (where you can define directories and paths to read from or to write to)